# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 Logo in the center of navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center my logo in the navbar, can I use or should I use grid layouts inside navbar or I should do something else:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <!-- I want this at the center of navbar -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png"/></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not? I should be able to redesign it somehow

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: center some navbar items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824914/bootstrap-center-some-navbar-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked before a few times, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824914/bootstrap-center-some-navbar-items).

I've set up a jsfiddle similar to your HTML provided, using your Gravatar since your logo wasn't available: http://jsfiddle.net/q68VS/

Important CSS:

```
.nav-center {
    margin:0;
    float:none;
}

.navbar-inner{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the accepted answer is using html for **Bootstrap 2**. However, I've come up with several ways to do this using **Bootstrap 3**. The simplest way to do this is probably using css translate.

```
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Live Demo**:
http://codepen.io/candid/pen/dGPZvR

This method also allows us to use background images for the logo and allows us to include text without having it show up in the display.

*HTML:*

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="http://disputebills.com">Brand Text</a>
```

*CSS:*

```
.navbar-brand {
  background: url(http://disputebills.com/site/uploads/2015/10/dispute.png) center / contain no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Live Demo**: http://codepen.io/candid/pen/NxWoJL

If for some reason you only want to do this on mobile display simply wrap .navbar-brand in a media query...

```
/* CENTER ON MOBILE ONLY */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-brand {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Comment: For flexbox approach see this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34150526/3123861

Answer (score -1):

The method shown by bwillis works nicelly, but I had to add some margin to my  navbar-collapse.
Then for me it was:

```
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.navbar-collapse {
        margin-top: 50px;
}
```

I also needed my navbar-nav centered,then I add:

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```