# brand logo center in navbar bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible in bootstrap 3 to center brand name in the middle of the menu item? For example there is four menu item, i want two items on the left side, and two on the right side and brand name in the middle of these two menu links. Thnaks in advance for the help.

Comment: This is exactly what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/34149840/3123861

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** Wrap a `<div class="pull-left">` around the two icons you want on the left

**Step 2** move this div before the `<a class="navbar-brand"`

**Step 3**
Wrap a `<div class="pull-right">` around the two icons you want on the right. Make sure this `div` follows the `navbar-brand`

This method can help you, however it is best if you post the relevant code here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It would be better if you gave the html code instead of writing step.

Comment: Fair point Anirudha. However, not having his code sample, I don't know how his looks like. The steps are a catch-all

Comment: thanks for the comment, i want a menu like this but in bootstrap 3.[codepen](http://codepen.io/wolfcry911/pen/HyLdg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nav-justified` class...

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav nav-justified">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Brand</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Demo: http://bootply.com/105175

Comment: This has some bugs in safari 8. If I'm not mistaken I believe it is going to be dropped in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Yes, the plan is to drop it in BS4: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#whats-removed

Answer (score 0):

Do it like my code. Get the anchor tag with `navbar-brand` out of the `navbar-header`and place it after the closing div. like in the code below.
navbar code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Left</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Place this code into your css file

```
.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    mar
}
```

Here is the link to the working example
http://www.bootply.com/98314

Answer (score 0):

You can use a much simpler approach too, just setting a percentage:

```
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

*Side Note: I haven't tested with IE. Usually I don't like percentages, but... it works!*

Comment: This puts it dead in the middle of the right edge. You would have to compensate by subtracting the size of the element, divide it by two etc. Too complicated.

Comment: You could also use this method by using css transform. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34150526/3123861