# Centering brand logo in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a Bootstrap 3 navbar so that the brand logo to always remain in the middle. This is the code:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" style="float: left;" class="pull-left btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand" style="margin: 0; float: none;" href="#">
      <img src="/Content/themes/next/images/logo.png" /></a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li> <a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="nextCog"></div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="navbar-text pull-right">superpup1 </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It makes a nice looking navbar:
[image]

However, I would like the logo (green) remain in the middle persistently. I am adding this style to the  tag with "brand" class:

```
<a class="brand" style="margin: 0; float: none; text-align:center" href="#">
  <img src="/Content/themes/next/images/logo.png" />
</a>
```

It partially solves the problem: the logo is in the middle but it pushes the rest of the navbar elements down:

[image]

This is an undesirable effect that I would like to eliminate. Could you suggest a solution? Maybe it's a wrong approach to centering a logo from the start ?

Comment: This looks like Bootstrap 2 to me

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try this:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
}
.brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
}
```

Centering your logo by 50% and minus half of your logo width so that it won't have problem when zooming in and out.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NsVkJ/)

Comment: I only wanted to center the logo on mobile (screen-sm) devices so I wrote a media query, set the position as absolute, offset the margin-left by 1/2 the width of the logo image, and set the left value to 50%. Works like a charm.

Comment: Change ".brand" to ".navbar-brand" and it will work.

Comment: You can now use `transform:translateX(-50%)` isntead of `margin-left` for this to work with any logo width.

Comment: @Lee, that's a much better solution. Also, for anyone in the future who uses the answer as-is, "logo width" is **inclusive** of padding. My logo image was 130px wide, but the default bootstrap padding added 30 extra pixels, so I had to use `margin-left: -80px !important;` in order to center mine appropriately. Just use `transform` as Lee suggested. It works better (in Chrome, at least).

Answer (score 61):

The simplest way is **css transform**:

```
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**DEMO: http://codepen.io/candid/pen/dGPZvR**

[image: centered background logo bootstrap 3]

---

This way also works with dynamically sized **background images** for the logo and allows us to utilize the text-hide class:

*CSS:*

```
.navbar-brand {
  background: url(http://disputebills.com/site/uploads/2015/10/dispute.png) center / contain no-repeat;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px; /* no height needed ... image will resize automagically */
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="http://disputebills.com">Brand Text
        </a>
```

---

We can also use flexbox though. However, using this method we'd have to move `navbar-brand` outside of `navbar-header`. This way is great though because we can now have image and text side by side:

[image: bootstrap 3 logo centered]

```
.brand-centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Demo: http://codepen.io/candid/pen/yeLZax**

To only achieve these results on mobile simply wrap the above css inside a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

}
```

Comment: I like your solution better!  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this might not work when the nav is collapsed!  Unable to click the button to drop down the menu!

Comment: @Hardycore didn't notice that. Easy fix though. I updated the codepen. Just need to add `.navbar-toggle { z-index: 1; }`

Answer (score 30):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2022)**

In Bootstrap 5, `mx-auto` or flexbox `justify-content-center` can still be used to center the brand and other elements.

https://codeply.com/p/UKfeHAJQQC

---

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2018)**

In Bootstrap 4, `mx-auto` or flexbox can be used to center the brand and other elements. See [How to center position navbar content in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167226/how-to-position-navbar-contents-in-bootstrap-4/43168976#43168976) for an explanation.

---

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer)**

See if this example helps: https://codeply.com/p/G71Uruhqwy

The brand is centered using..

```
.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Your markup is for Bootstrap 2, not 3. There is no longer a `navbar-inner`.

EDIT - Another approach is using `transform: translateX(-50%);`

```
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/3kkmEHtVGH

---

Also see:

[Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-and-right-aligned-items/20362024#20362024)

Comment: The "edit" solution is perfect. I had to use this approach vs the more simple absolute centering one because it was messing with my site's google analytics and extending across the page.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but just for posterity.

I've found the easiest way to do it is to have the image as the background image of the navbar-brand. Just makes sure to put in a custom width.

```
.navbar-brand
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 150px;
    background-image: url('logo.png');
}
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me with dynamic brand image sizes

Answer (score 0):

A solution where the logo is truly centered and the links are justified.

The max recommended number of links for the nav is 6, depending on the length of the words in eache link.

If you have 5 links, insert an empty link and style it with:

```
class="hidden-xs" style="visibility: hidden;"
```

in this way the number of links is always even.

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  #site-logo {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    bottom: -35px;
  }
  #site-logo a {
    margin-top: -53px;
  }
</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Nav</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav center-block">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">First Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third Link</a></li>
        <li id="site-logo" class="hidden-xs"><a href="#"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32877/logo-thing.png" width="200" alt="Logo Thing main logo"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fourth Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fifth Link</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs" style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="#">Sixth Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

To see result click on **run snippet** and then **full page**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bj5dhef/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.navbar-brand {
 margin: auto;
}
</style>

<!--HTML-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand"  href="#">
  <img src="logo goes here" width="100" height="100" class="logo" alt="" 
loading="lazy">
</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's a flexbox (and probably due to a `justify-content:space-between` BT4 css prop.), if you add a third element, sibling of the name and the button, it wil naturaly centering the second element in the code.

I just add `<span>login</span>` just after the a

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mt-5">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <span>login</span>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```