# One Pull Left, One Pull Right, but how do I center between?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Seen at http://www.gerddagne.com

I want to center that gallery logo.  I have tried this link but cannot get the centering to work correctly - [Centering brand logo in Bootstrap 3 Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400234/centering-brand-logo-in-bootstrap-3-navbar)

My css is very outdated :(

Comment: Maybe try flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Comment: The `GERD DAGNE` part? how about the other image in nav?

Comment: I meant the agora gallery logo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also center like this - add to your .pull-right
what this will do will center that entire div inside its parent div. So in your case you also have the pinterest and facebook social media links inside it. they will be included in the centering.

### CSS

```
position:absolute;
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Thank you as long as I give it it's own div this works as inteded, I only wanted to center the gallery logo not the facebook/pininterest icons

Comment: No problem mate :) happy to help, yep it has to be in its own div to keep your media links to the right

Answer (score 0):

For the start if it is okay to customize your Bootstrap, you can remove the **Pull Right** Class from it. And give it a custom class (something like *center-logo*)

```css3
.center-logo{
  margin: 0 auto important;
  width: 230px;
}
```

Usually the *margin: 0 auto;* works when the *width* is known. That means *230px* is a variable which is the width of the content within the div encapsulating the logo and your social media icons (facebook and pinterest). However as you noticed this centers your social icons too. Maybe you move them to another div and apply the *pull right* class to that div

Comment: I wanted to keep my pull right for the social icons.