# Navbar Collapse bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm using navbar collapse from bootstrap.
And i have website that the location of the logo is in center. when it collapse i want the logo still in center. but my problem is the logo get collapse too.

here is my pic:
[image]

here is the collapse:
[image]

i want the collapse to be like this:
[image]

here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: orange;"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: orange;"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: orange;"></span> 
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" style="text-align: center;">
            <nav  id = "navigasi" class = "pull-left" style = "display : inline-block; margin: 70px 0px 0px 40px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href ="#" class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a role = "menuitem" href="#">Wedding</a></li>
                            <li><a role = "menuitem" href="#">Pre-Wedding</a></li>
                            <li><a role = "menuitem" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a class = "" href ="index.html" style = "display : inline-block;">
                <img src="image/logo.png" style = "height : 200px; ">
            </a>
            <nav  id = "navigasi" class = "pull-right" style = "display : inline-block; margin: 70px 40px 0px 0px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    
                    <li><a href="#">Jadwal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tentang Kami</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kontak.html">Kontak</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, my collapse is so bad and the navbar locate on the left and right. how can i fix this? please help me. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400234/centering-brand-logo-in-bootstrap-3-navbar have a look at this

Comment: wow thankyou bro. i aprreciated it!