# center image into nav header in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

i created a navbar header with the new bootstrap 4 alpha frame work.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top pulse-header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-left">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="open-pulse-sidebar"><i class="ion-grid pulse-icons"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="toggle-search"><i class="ion-ios-search-strong pulse-icons"></i></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="open-notification-sidebar">
                <i class="ion-earth pulse-icons"></i>
                <span class="pulse-circle"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="open-chat-sidebar"><i class="ion-chatboxes pulse-icons"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
.pulse-header {
  height: 60px;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  background-color: #1f2532;
  padding: 13px 15px;
}

.pulse-header .navbar-nav-left {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.pulse-header .nav > .nav-item {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.pulse-header .nav > .nav-item > a {
  position: relative;
}
```

i would like to have a logo centered in the navbar but do not know how to get it done, cause when i put on into, my icons on the right side are moving down.

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/tZ9tzdX9jA)

Comment: Like this? ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400234/centering-brand-logo-in-bootstrap-3-navbar

Comment: Is this all the content you you will have in the `nav` for the time being?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You just need one block of css

Here is a working example of how I achieved what you're are looking for.

I added an `img` tag as a child of the `nav` bar and then set it to bellow code.

### Try this:

```
.navbar img {
     display:block;
     margin: 0px auto;
}
```

In the event that when you begin to populate the `navbar` you find that the logo no longer centers then attempt this code for your logo

### Or try this:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
}
```

This method will not be as automatic however will work if your content beigns to offset the logo.

#### Working Example: http://www.bootply.com/XVlsafgbzD