# How to render/align logo in the center using twitter-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, svg

I am beginner and learning web development and I have got one **svg logo**, and I want to set it up **vertically-center** of the nav bar. I am not sure how to do that properly.

Issue: the image/svg is going out of the `navbar-brand`.

[image]

Image has a `logo` class where I have put a width like below:

```
.logo {
    width: 145px;
}
```

Question: Why does my logo is **going out of the parent** `navbar brand` class. Also, I tried `vertical-align: middle` but this also does not help. Can someone guide me how to put svg logo, so that it remains **vertically-center** and do no go out of parent div.

Attempt 1:

`vertical-align: middle` in `logo` class

Attempt 2:

`center-block in navbar-brand`

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400234/centering-brand-logo-in-bootstrap-3-navbar Already answered here

Comment: That is different. It talks about making to logo horizontally center.

Comment: @KartikPuri: I did not ask my question properly, added more texts now.

Answer (score 0):

In this JSFiddle there is an example to vertically center the logo

[Vertically center logo](http://jsfiddle.net/nD4tW/)

```
 line-height: 50px;
```