# center bootstrap navbar-brand image/logo

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add navbar-brand logo, but the logo does not fit into navbar and when I set image height and width to 100%,

`img{height:100%; width:100%;}` the logo becomes compressed.

How can I change the size of bootstrap navbar to properly center navbar-brand image/logo without affecting the height and width of the image ?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering brand logo in Bootstrap 3 Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400234/centering-brand-logo-in-bootstrap-3-navbar)

Comment: the image is compressed inside the navbar when i set img height and weight to 100%