# How to change the order of bootstrap navbar Logo from left to center

Tags: javascript, html, css

**i need to ask how to change Bootstrap 4 Navbar ordering because currently logo in left side but i want it become in the center and both side i have menu. can help me how to change this order?**

### Current Navbar Image check out please

[image: Current Navbar Image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navigation-clean" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-once="true" style="background-color:rgb(16,34,55);" data-toggle="affix">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="assets/img/logo.svg" class="largeLogo" id="Logo"></a>
        <!-- links toggle -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" style="color: #FFC000"></i>
        </button>
    <!-- account toggle -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fa fa-user" style="color: #FFC000"></i>
    </button>



            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav align-items-center ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse"><a class="nav-link text-warning hvr-underline-from-center" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" style="width:18px;"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse"><a class="nav-link text-warning hvr-underline-from-center" href="#cor"><i class="fa fa-book" style="width:18px;"></i>Courses</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse"><a class="nav-link text-warning hvr-underline-from-center" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" style="width:18px;"></i>About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse"><a class="nav-link text-warning hvr-underline-from-center" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star" style="width:18px;"></i>Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse"><a class="nav-link text-warning hvr-underline-from-center" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="width:18px;"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse"><a class="nav-link text-warning hvr-underline-from-center" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" style="width:18px;"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse"><a class="nav-link text-warning hvr-underline-from-center" href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-googleplus" style="width:18px;"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="account">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto align-items-end">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>



    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering brand logo in Bootstrap 3 Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400234/centering-brand-logo-in-bootstrap-3-navbar)

Answer (score 0):

u should search a little bit more because it's common question

```
 .navbar {
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
        display: block;
    }
```