# Centering Logo in Bootstrap 3 Navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a CodePen where I'm working on mock-mobile version of a casino site using Bootstrap. The visibility classes is are in play to make it appear only when on small or extra-small screens.

There's a logo in the navbar that I can't seem to get centered "correctly". I need the the logo to take into context the full width of the bar and not just the full width minus the area of the toggle.

Here my full page [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bmoneruiux/full/6eb14c6e6fc671e27c70c5089b6ddd2c/)

And here is a [casino website that is actually implementing what I speak of](http://m.soaringeaglecasino.com), I just can't see how they're doing it. I found a question on here that SEEMED to be close to what I wanted "[Located Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284778/twitter-bootstrap-3-0-logo-in-the-center-of-navbar)". It suggested the wrapping of code with DIVs that correspond to this CSS (but it still didn't work):

```
.nav-center {
    margin:0;
    float:none;
}

.navbar-inner{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Took some time, but I added this...

```
.navbar-brand img {
  width: 197px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This sorted everything right out. I applied to my CodePen as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100vw` or `width: 100%` to `.navbar-header`

Comment: Hey Tambo. Thanks for this as I did forget about that.

Comment: Tambo. Your suggestion definitely helped get it near the center. I've updated my code to reflect changes I was doing locally. It's still not 100% centered and driving me crazy.

Comment: @bmoneruxui add `text-align: center;` to `navbar-header` and `.navbar-brand img {
width: 197px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 8px 0px;
}`