# Boostrap navbar center content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I need to center some content in bootstrap navbar

trying and copy from other post but isn't working...

[Bootstrap: center some navbar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824914/bootstrap-center-some-navbar-items/17824969#17824969)

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bdp2xxwb/)

my code:

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav ul  > .center-nav  {
    display: inline-block !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    text-align:center !important;
    width:70% !important;    
}
.navbar-nav > .center-nav ul, .navbar-nav > .center-nav li  a {
    display: inline !important;
    float: none !important;
    line-height: 40px !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Left <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>                       
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav center-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">center</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">center</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your center navigation after the right in your markup. Remove floats, display the center nav items as `inline-block` and align them centrally.

Note that since this changes the order of your markup, a mobile device will list the right navigation items before the centre ones.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Left <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>               
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav center-nav">
                <li><a href="#">center</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">center</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .center-nav{
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .center-nav > li{
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bdp2xxwb/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are wanting to center the `li's` with the class name `center-nav`.

Add the following to your `css` if that's what you are looking for:

```
.center-nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using this Bootstrap class:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">right</a></li>
</ul>



navbar-right
```

Which clearly floats that part of the navbar to the right.

You should try to look into the classes you are using, especially if taken from a framework, and ESPECIALLY if taken directly from a template.

The `!important` will have no effect if your custom CSS comes before the Bootstrap CSS, which is probably what's happening.

Comment: Your questions states that you want your navbar items centered.